# Foreign key field disappears in swagger docs after adding depth attribute in Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

Whenever I define the `depth` attribute, the foreign key field from swagger docs in POST section disappears. That seems strange because I required `depth = 1` when I want related data in my `GET` request. So I can not remove this in order to get this related field parameter in the `POST` section.

*Here is the case.*

**Model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=255)
    completed = models.BooleanField("Completed")
```

**Serializer** without `depth =1`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Todo

class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Todo
```

**Swagger output:**
[image]

Now If I add `depth = 1` than **Swagger does not display related field**.
[image]

Let me know if anyone has any clue about this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after digging into this, I come up with solution by which we can avoid this issue and achieve the expected solution.

So the solution is "Instead of using `depth = 1` attribute we can using related serializer instance it self where it works similar to `depth` functionality."

**Here is tested solution**

**Model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=255)
    completed = models.BooleanField("Completed")
```

**Serializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.conf import settings
from models import Todo

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = User


class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   user = UserSerializer() 

   class Meta:
      model = Todo
      fields = ('user', 'title', 'completed')
```

**Swagger Output:**
[image]

This solution is kind of different approach in order to achieve the required functionality, But still I am expecting an official solution from `django-rest-swagger` team, Even I have posted the same query on django-rest-swagger github repo [here](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/393).

Comment: I was also having this problem in POST request, the foreign keys were not shown in browsable api. I was able to do so after removing depth=1.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to just don't use `depth` and override `to_representation` method of serializer:

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        r = super(TodoSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        r.update({'user': UserSerializer().to_representation(instance.user)})
        return r
```

This way, in post everything will be as it was, and in get when return json of `todo` then `to_representation` will be called and will add user to json data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your serialzer as follows

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
creator = serializers.RelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = ("name", "task", "creator")
    depth = 1
```

you need to mentions fields and RelatedField in your serializers

Comment: Thanks, Let me check this out and will let you know.

Comment: This is not working as its giving this error `RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field user. If you do not need to support write operations you probably want to subclass `ReadOnlyField` instead.`

Comment: I don't want to change the field name as well because It will be used in POST request.